# Is it possible to modify ASP.NET MVC WebGrid so that it doesn't look like a regular grid table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I need to render a table that doesn't look like a regular grid table, where for one entry, which would be a row in a typical table, columns 1 and 2 values can be put in row 1, columns 3, 4 and 5 values will be in row 2, and so on like so:

```
<table id="display_searchresults_student">
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="4"><img src="../../Images/picture_temp.jpg" id="display_searchresults_studentpicture"/></th>
                            <td id="display_searchresults_studentname"><a href="">**Name Column**</a>
                            <img src="../../Images/picture_temp.jpg" height="25px" width="25px"/>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" width="100px">Rating Column</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="display_searchresults_studentlocation">City Column, State Column | University Column</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="display_searchresults_studentinfo">Department Column | School Standing Column Graduation Date Column | GPA Column</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="display_searchresults_studentdesc" colspan="2">Comments Column<a href="">...</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

This table will have multiple entries. The reason why I thought of using a WebGrid is because I need the sorting, filtering and paging capability. I now that Telerik allows constructing tables like that. However, I'm not seeing how to do it through the WebGrid. Is there a way to change the Webgrid's HTML prior to it being rendered without breaking the sorting, filtering and paging capabilities? Does jqGrid or other open-source grids allow to do something like that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are talking about without an example, but what about  [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com)?

Comment: Take a look at the clarification above, please.

Comment: Can you draw a little picture?